# Difference between "was determined" and "determine"?

Tags: sentence-construction

From [an article in *The Times of India*](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/trichy/mom-sets-girl-ablaze-in-tamil-nadu-to-stop-marriage-with-dalit-friend/articleshow/72151744.cms):

> Class XI student girl, a native of Vazhmangalam village in
>   Nagapattinam, **was determined** to marry the 22-year-old Rajkumar who
>   hails from the same area.

Why is **"was determined"** used in the above sentence? Which tense or voice is it?

Is it something describing girl rather than action to be performed by her?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Was' is the simple past tense of 'to be' and 'determined' is an adjective meaning "showing the strong desire to follow a particular plan of action even if it is difficult".

[Determined (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/determined)

Comment: can we use **was wanted** as an Adjective.

Comment: @user4084 - yes. Past participle of verb functioning as adjective.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey *"Class XI student girl **was wanted** to marry the 22-year-old Rajkumar"* would be incorrect.

Comment: @user4084 No, you can't.  Also, you can show that *determined* is an adjective in this sentence with a *very*-test: "The girl was **very** determined to marry him" is grammatical, but it wouldn't be with a verb.

Comment: She could be wanted as a bride.

Comment: Thanks... "Girl who was keenly wanted to marry" would be an adjective.